# My stack frames are different from the legacy one

Tags: c, gcc, stack, gdb

Here's how a stack frame should look:

```
(high memory addresses)
    -function arguments
    -return address
    -saved frame pointer
    -local variables
(low memory addresses)
```

The question is why my stack frames look like that:

```
(high memory addresses)
    -return address
    -saved frame pointer
    -local variables
    -function arguments
(low memory addresses)
```

I noticed it while debugging in gdb.
I code in C and compile with gcc 5.4.0 on Kali Linux x86_64(intel core i7).

C code:

```
void test_function(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    int flag;
    char buffer[10];
    flag = 31337;
    buffer[0] = 'A';
}

int main() {
    test_function(1, 2, 3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Value of rbp in main:

```
0x7fffffffe260
```

Assembly instruction after test_functtion call address:

```
0x00000000004004e1
```

Result of x command on rsp while being in the test_function frame:

```
0x7fffffffe240: 0x00000004  0x00000003  0x00000002  0x00000001
0x7fffffffe250: 0x00400441  0x00000000  0x004003b0  0x00007a69
0x7fffffffe260: 0xffffe270  0x00007fff  0x004004e1  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe270: 0x004004f0  0x00000000  0xf7a575f0  0x00007fff
```

Comment: Because the stack grows _downwards_.

Comment: I know but if you reverse it, it doesn't even correspond.

Comment: "Here's how a stack frame should look:". Where did you get that from?

Comment: Each time I go on Google and type stack frame diagram, that's the only thing I get and i read a book called "hacking: the art of exploitation" and it is the same diagram(the guy who wrote the book was also using gcc).

Comment: I think you may be misinterpreting some of the information. Firstly, your addressing  in that first diagram is upside down as already pointed out. Secondly please show us the code and gdb output (or other info) that you used to come up with the second diagram.

Comment: sorry, the first time I got it the other way around, but i just corrected it for the second diagram too.

Comment: the compiler is right, there is no reason that one version of gcc has to be compatible with another, it only has to be compatible with itself.  Same goes for any other compiler and no reason to expect their objects to cross link.

Comment: are you using the exact same version and build options as that used in the book/reference?

Comment: No, I don't think so, why?

Comment: Why I haven't seen any stack frame diagram of this type on internet?

Comment: I still don't see how you got from the gdb output to your second diagram. I don't think your conclusions are correct. Please state explicitly how you think the gdb data results in that second diagram. And please show exactly how you got `Value of rbp in main: 0x004004f0`. That value does not look like a stack address.

Comment: Sorry, I got the rbp value wrong

Comment: now the problem is that the function arguments are supposed to be higher in memory

Comment: @dwelch Not true. Libraries on a Linux box need to be compatible regardless of which compiler was used to generate them. Someone may create a library with clang, another with gcc, another with the intel compiler. You can link with the libraries without knowing how they were generated. There is is an [ABI spec](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) they all have to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the specification of a stack frame has changed significantly between x86 and x86_64. You are correct for a x86 stack frame ([Intel386 Processor Supplement](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf)). The x86_64 spec ([AMD64 Architecture Support Supplement](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf)) however passes integer arguments in registers (paragraph 3.2.3). Item #2 below:

> 1. If the class is MEMORY, pass the argument on the stack.
> 2. If the class is INTEGER, the next available register of the sequence rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8 and %r9 is used 13 .
> 3. If the class is SSE, the next available vector register is used, the registers are taken in the order from %xmm0 to %xmm7.
> 4. If the class is SSEUP, the eightbyte is passed in the next available eightbyte chunk of the last used vector register.
> 5. If the class is X87, X87UP or COMPLEX_X87, it is passed in memory.

The stack frame now looks like this:

[image: x86_64 stack frame]

If you look at the stack frame, the return address in main is 8[%rbp] or 0x004005be and the arguments are in the correct registers:

```
(gdb) x/32 $rbp
0x7fffffffe040: 0xffffe050  0x00007fff  0x004005be  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe050: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xf7a36f45  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe060: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xffffe138  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe070: 0x00000000  0x00000001  0x004005a1  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe080: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xdf5e7534  0x8acdbc8c
0x7fffffffe090: 0x00400470  0x00000000  0xffffe130  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe0a0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe0b0: 0x1f9e7534  0x75324373  0x02a47534  0x753253ca
(gdb) info registers 
rax            0x4005a1 4195745
rbx            0x0  0
rcx            0x4  4
rdx            0x3  3
rsi            0x2  2
rdi            0x1  1
....
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer